# Mariadb doesn't starts. Control process Exited

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7

I am trying to start mariadb with `systemctl start mariadb` also tried using sudo along.

This is what it says

> Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl
>   -xe" for details.

I saw this at many places but nothing helped.

It fails, I removed, installed again, nothing happened.

This is a part of /var/log/messages

```
Jun 17 18:03:09 controller systemd: Starting MariaDB 10.1 database
server... 
Jun 17 18:03:09 controller mysqld: 2016-06-17 18:03:09 140477178509440
       [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.12-MariaDB) starting as process 120408 ... 
Jun 17 18:03:12 controller systemd: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE 
Jun 17 18:04:13 controller systemd: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=3 
Jun 17 18:04:13 controller systemd: Failed to start MariaDB 10.1 database server. 
Jun 17 18:04:13 controller systemd: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state. 
Jun 17 18:04:13 controller systemd: mariadb.service failed.
```

I am really new to CentOS and mariadb, so I don't know how to proceed.

**EDIT**

The mariadb.log says

> 2016-06-17 19:24:39 140652810123392 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
>   2016-06-17 19:24:39 140652810123392 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 98: Address already in use
>   2016-06-17 19:24:39 140652810123392 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ? 2016-06-17 19:24:39 140652810123392 [ERROR] Aborting

This is my my.cnf

```
#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# This group is read by the server
#
[mysqld]
port=5555
bind-address = 10.23.77.68
default-storage-engine = innodb
innodb_file_per_table
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

I tried adding a line in my.cnf

```
port=5555
```

Didn't help, mariadb.log says the same thing as I have mentioned earlier.

Comment: Do you have mariaDB logs /var/log/mysql/* you should see some error log there, see if there is more data than what you see in messages. What port are you running db on? Is it being blocked by another program?

Comment: I have /var/log/mysqld.log
Please enter more information as in the exact commands or place to look into. I am really new to all this and Linux.

Comment: I also have /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log

Comment: any errors  that make sense in either file? if you type ps aux | grep -i mysql do you see it running? If so, what happens if you stop mysql and start mariadb?

Comment: The mariadb.log says 

2016-06-17 19:24:39 140652810123392 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-17 19:24:39 140652810123392 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 98: Address already in use
2016-06-17 19:24:39 140652810123392 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-06-17 19:24:39 140652810123392 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: I tried ` systemctl stop mysqld`
Doesn't helps...

Comment: Seems you have Mysql running on the same machine. Do you have anything using mysql in that server? If not, then you might want to stop it, disable it or remove it. If it is being used, I'd create a new port for and see if this does the trick. You might want to use localhost vs 127.0.0.1 in the config

Comment: inside /etc/my.cnf see if you can change the port

Comment: I posted the my.cnf above in the edit... I don't see anything for port

Comment: Try on [path_to_mariadb]/bin/my.ini and see if the port configuration is there.

Comment: @JorgeCampos How to know  [path_to_mariadb], I just did yum install. Don't know where does it goes.

Comment: `find / -name mysql` I am use to Ubuntu there normally it is on var/lib/mysql do not know on centos

Comment: There is var/lib/mysql , the contents are following : 
`aria_log.00000001`     `ib_logfile0`        `mysql_upgrade_info`
`aria_log_control`    `ib_logfile1`         `performance_schema/`
`ibdata1`             `mysql/`              `test/`

Comment: Your log tells you another program on your server is already using port 3306, the tcp/ip port for your sql server.  To find what program, use this from the shell: `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 3306`.  You may need to stop a mysql server to start the mariadb server.

Comment: See it the bin folder is under the `/etc/lib/mysql` folder

Comment: @MitchJackson
It says tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2954/mysqld
can't I change the port? I tried `port=5555` in my.cnf , but it didn't help

Comment: You already have a mysql server running on that port.  It could be you installed both mysql and mariadb and are trying to run them at the same time, or something you installed has a bundled mysql server built in.  Try `systemctl stop mysqld` before running `systemctl start mariadb`

Comment: @MitchJackson Didn't work

Comment: The number 2954 you got from netstat is the process id (pid) of the mysql server that is ALREADY RUNNING.  You can't start another one while that one is still running.  You can stop that one with `sudo kill 2954` perhaps, but you should find out where it came from before trying to start another one

Comment: This question is clearly resolved.

Comment: Sorry was offline for 2 days, I was able to solve it using `fuser -k 3306/tcp` , I guess `sudo kill 2954` is doing the same thing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fuser -k 3306/tcp` will solve the probem.
-k is to  Kill processes accessing the file.

Answer (score 4):

I solved as follows:

1. After installing
2. Run: > `mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/`
3. Then: >`mysql_secure_installation`
4. And then: `systemctl start mariadb`

With this this, I can resolved.

Comment: the 2. command did solve my issue. but I don't understand why that's the only problem I have now. Normally the MariaDb was working fine only to wake up one morning and it is down while trying to start it, it couldn't then it comes your solution and boom it is up again. nothing changed base Dir and data dir was in that same paths

Answer (score 1):

Just remove following files at location

> /var/lib/mysql

- ib_logfile0
- ib_logfile1